# Prove that inequality $\sum_{cyc} \frac{a}{b+2}\le 1$

Tags: inequality, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

> For $a,b,c>0$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3=3$ prove that $$\frac{a}{b+2}+\frac{b}{c+2}+\frac{c}{a+2}\le 1$$

---

We have:$$a^3+1+1+b^3+1+1+c^3+1+1\ge 3\left(a+b+c\right)$$

$$\Rightarrow 3\left(a+b+c\right)\le a^3+b^3+c^3+6\le 9\Rightarrow a+b+c\le 3$$

Use AM-GM:

$$\frac{a}{b+2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(a-\frac{ab}{b+2}\right)\ge \frac{1}{2}\left(a-\frac{ab}{\sqrt{2b}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(a-\frac{a\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

$$\Rightarrow LHS\le \frac{1}{2}\left(a+b+c-\frac{a\sqrt{b}+b\sqrt{c}+c\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\le 1$$

Need prove:$a\sqrt{b}+b\sqrt{c}+c\sqrt{a}\ge \sqrt{2}$

Help me prove that last inequality

Comment: Shouldn't the last inequality be $a\sqrt{b} + b\sqrt{c} + c \sqrt{a} \ge \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: ok thanks fixed

Comment: @WordShallow That error comes from the penultimate line. You should have LHS $\ge$

Comment: My try is wrong, you can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$8+abc\geq2(a^2+b^2+c^2)+a^2c+b^2a+c^2b.$$
By Holder $$27=(1+1+1)(a^3+b^3+c^3)^2\geq(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3,$$
which says that $a^2+b^2+c^2\leq3$.
Thus, it's enough to prove that $$2+abc\geq a^2c+b^2a+c^2b$$
and since $3\geq a^2+b^2+c^2,$ it's enough to prove that
$$2\left(\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}+abc\geq a^2c+b^2a+c^2b.$$
But the last inequality is homogeneous, which says that we can assume $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$ and we need to prove that $2+abc\geq a^2c+b^2a+c^2b.$

Now, let $\{a,b,c\}=\{x,y,z\}$ such that $x\geq y\geq z$.

Hence, by Rearrangement and AM-GM we obtain:
$$a^2c+b^2a+c^2b-abc=a\cdot{ac}+b\cdot{ba}+c\cdot{cb}-xyz\leq$$
$$\leq x\cdot{xy}+y\cdot{xz}+z\cdot{yz}-xyz=y(x^2+z^2)=y(3-y^2)\leq2$$
and we are done!

Comment: Nice proof, Michael!

Comment: I think you should use AMGM $a^3+a^3+1\ge 3a^2$ instead $(1+1+1)(a^3+b^3+c^3)\ge (a^2+b^2+c^2)^2$ it's wrong.

Comment: @Word Shallow It was typo. I fixed. See now.